# react-native error with undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs

Lately i've been trying to link my js on component folder but suddenly the issue came out. The first issue is referrence error which occurs because i make typo mistakes on import section. But then ,on 2nd trial by running the emulator i got 'Type Error: Undefined is not an object (props.albums.title)'

Here's my Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
   return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
       {props.children}
      </View>
   );
};

const styles = {
   containerStyle: {
       borderWidht: 1,
       borderRadius: 2,
       borderColor: '#ddd',
       borderBottomWidth: 0,
       shadowColor: '#000',
       shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
       shadowOpacity: 0.1,
       shadowRadius: 2,
       elevation: 1,
       marginLeft: 5,
       marginRight: 5,
       marginTOp: 10
   }
};

export default Card;
```

here is the AlbumDetail

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';

const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default AlbumDetail;
```

here is the AlbumList

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';


class AlbumList extends Component {
 state={ albums: [] };


 componentWillMount() {
  axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
  .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
  }
  renderAlbums() {
  return this.state.albums.map(album => <AlbumDetail key={album.title} record={album} />);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderAlbums()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}  


export default AlbumList;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
renderAlbums(){
  if(this.state.albums=='undefined'){
   //handle Error
   }else{
    return this.state.albums.map(album => <AlbumDetail key={album.title} record={album} />)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must catch the error `undefined` which is generated by the array. You declare an empty array in the state.